# Issues implementing symbol resolution for crash handling on an executable compiled with Mingw-w64

Tags: c, windows, mingw, mingw-w64, c11

I'm developing a C (NOT C++) application for Windows using the Mingw-w64 toolchains. As part of the functionality I'm in need of a crash handler and as such, have been searching for solutions. I should mention that I WILL NOT utilize MSVC toolchains on Windows since my codebase is GCC-based (I frequently use GCC extensions/built-ins), I much prefer using open-source toolchains, and portability reasons. Naturally this limits my options by quite a bit. MinGW-based toolchains do compile debug information but not to a format that Windows debugging APIs and tools understand; it would seem that MinGW toolchains use the DWARF format and embed it directly into the final PE image. Before my question gets tagged as a duplicate I would like to point out that there's really not any questions with respect to MinGW compilers that have been properly answered subject to my constraints.

As for my proposed solutions, I have looked into a variety of dedicated crash handling libraries but they all seem to assume Visual Studio toolchains on Windows or GCC on a Linux system. [Google Breakpad](https://github.com/DaemonEngine/breakpad) looks like a mature project compatible with MinGW but it's really a bit overkill for what I want. I'm looking for something a little more lightweight. I found a great single-header library called [b_stacktrace](https://github.com/iboB/b_stacktrace) that seems to do exactly what I want it to do except resolve symbols since it naturally assumes a MSVC toolchain. While searching on how to fix this issue, I found [a great article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/01/13/exceptions-stack-traces-c/) which uses a program called [addr2line](https://linux.die.net/man/1/addr2line) (probably originally ported from binutils on Linux to Mingw toolchains in the form of an executable PE) to resolve the symbols on Windows.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
/* Resolve symbol name and source location given the path to the executable 
   and an address */
int addr2line(char const * const program_name, void const * const addr)
{
  char addr2line_cmd[512] = {0};
 
  /* have addr2line map the address to the relent line in the code */
  #ifdef __APPLE__
    /* apple does things differently... */
    sprintf(addr2line_cmd,"atos -o %.256s %p", program_name, addr); 
  #else
    sprintf(addr2line_cmd,"addr2line -f -p -e %.256s %p", program_name, addr); 
  #endif
 
  /* This will print a nicely formatted string specifying the
     function and source line of the address */
  return system(addr2line_cmd);
}
```

However, the solution involves directly calling the executable which is out of the question to me. I'd rather not manually bundle another EXE with my application just for error handling. Not to mention the [security issues](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152177) with using the `system` function.

I plan to simply fork the `b_stacktrace` library by embedding addr2line's functionality directly into the header file. If it can't resolve the symbols using the standard win32 APIs, it will call addr2line functions instead assuming that the PE is probably a MinGW compiled PE. And if all of that fails, then it will default to displaying the raw hex addresses. However, the problem with this stratedgy is that I can't find the source code for the ported version addr2line bundled with the MinGW-w64 toolchains. I did look in the MinGW-w64 source code repositories but couldn't find the source code for the Windows port. All I could find, without much surprise, are versions of the [source code for Linux systems](https://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/addr2line/addr2line.c).

My questions are thusly: Is this a good implementation plan? If so, where is the source code for the `addr2line.exe` bundled with MinGW-w64 toolchains? If not, is there a more elegant solution to my woes that does not involve using some very large library just to print stacktraces?

Comment: In MSYS2 `addr2line` is a part of the binutils package, [here's its build script](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-binutils/PKGBUILD).

Comment: In looking at the build script am I to understand that addr2line wasn't actually ported to Windows but crosscompiled or something?

Comment: It doesn't seem they're cross-compiling, since `--target` and `--host` are the same.

Comment: Consider just using breakpad/crashpad. We're using the latter at work (with MSVC though), and all we do is initialize it with a single function, specifying the path to write dumps to.

Comment: I use C more than C++ myself and I keep away from MSVC too. I'm not a big fan of exception handling the way it's done in languages as C++ and Java, because a lot of the time it gives developers an excuse to write ugly code, that is allowed to continue after something got messed up. Unfortunately in C the alternative is to catch all the bad scenario's (use `if` to check for `NULL` pointers, check if `malloc()` or `strdup()` actually allocated memory, etc.). This can add quite some code overhead, but in makes your code more solid and forces you to think of ways your code/algorithms can go wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat On a second glance, Google Breakpad won't work since it's written in C++ and my entire application is C11.

Comment: @BrechtSanders I know that coding safely is the best thing to do, but unexpected errors always happen when end-users get a hold of an application. I need a way to handle these in stride despite best practices. I already do my best to mitigate memory safety bugs using your advice, however, I don't always have the luxury of never making an error. If you happen to know an elegant solution to my woes, I would be incredibly grateful. I've done a lot of research but nothing seems suitable.

Comment: *"my entire application is C11"* Making a single .cpp file to init breakpad shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I usually do a lot of testing with valgrind (unfortunately not available for Windows). Fuzzing is also a technique used to see how all kinds of input can break your program. A very basic thing to do is include assertions in your code to see if things that should not happen are happening anyway. But catching errors exception-style like in C++ won't really work in C I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you even need a library to get a minidump file? Why not let Windows [take care](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) of that?